# In C++, how do i use like strncmp function in C?

Tags: c++, c

In C++, Isn`t there string function like `strncmp()` in C ???

for example

```
string str1 = "abc";
string str2 = "ab";

str2.compare(0,1,str1) == 0
```

is it possible??

Comment: C++ is not C. I suggest you read a good C++ book. You can use == directly, since there are a lot of operators define for std::string.

Comment: Have you tried running the code you posted?

Comment: the result is -1...

Comment: i want to compare in length 2.

Comment: You can use `strncmp()` in C++, too. Even if it´s not the most recommended thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the class std::string has the member function compare declared for you use case like

```
int compare(size_type pos1, size_type n1, basic_string_view<charT, traits> sv) const;
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows using this overloaded member function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string str1 = "abc";
    std::string str2 = "ab";

    std::cout << str2.compare( 0, 1 ,str1) << '\n';
    std::cout << str1.compare(  0, 2 , str2) << '\n';
    std::cout << str2.compare( str1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << str2.compare( 1, 1, str1 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-2
0
-1
1
```

So if two strings are equal then the function returns 0. If the first string is less than the second string then the function returns a negative value. Otherwise the function returns a positive value.

Comment: @KimYeongHHo It is a condition. So it is evaluates to false.

Comment: omg... i used `//` before `#include <string>..... thanks for your answer :(

Comment: Something strange. 
why the result is `str2.compare(0, 1, str1)`  -2??? is not 0???

Comment: @KimYeongHHo It is because there is compare str2.substr( 0, 1 ) with str1. That is there are compared objects "a" and  "abc" .

Comment: ah....So, Do str2.substr(0, 1) with str1 and str2.compare(0, 1, str1) mean the same thing?

Comment: @KimYeongHHo In the both cases in fact the one character is compared with a whole string.

Answer (score 5):

You can compare `std::string` directly:

```
if (str1 == str2)
```

To compare up to length 2, use [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare):

```
if (str2.compare(0, 2, str1) == 0)
```

You can also use C functions in C++ if you include the corresponding C header, for example to use `string.h`, include `<cstring>`.

Comment: This will work, but each call to `substr` creates a new temporary object. That's expensive.

Comment: I want to compare about length 2

Comment: @KimYeongHHo then compare str.length()

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has overloaded its '==' operator. Just `if (a == b)` works.
Interestingly even `(a < b)` works and applies a lexical ordering.

EDIT: Since the TE seems to ask about the equality of the length of strings after all, not their actual letters:

```
if (str1.length() == str2.length())
{

}
```

Comment: I want to compare about length  2 :( 
then, How I do ..??

Comment: sorry about confusion. i want to actual letters in length 2